# Hi, I am trying to write a code, which uses nav_msgs's OccupancyGrid

Tags: ros, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to write a code, which uses `nav_msgs`'s `OccupancyGrid`, to visualize the grid map like a potential field.

I'm inserting the probability of where an obstacle might move next into `OccupancyGrid.data[]`.
`data[]` was declared as `Int8` so I am inserting numbers from 0 to 100.
I'm pretty sure that rviz should show each sell white or gray or black, but in my code some parts become red.

I want to add up the inserted data each time so that when multiple objects collide, the `data[]` becomes 100 and shows a black area.
At the end of the program, I wrote a for loop so that when the value of `data[]` is over 100, that value becomes exactly 100.

Here's the part of the code where I'm having trouble with...

```
map.data[p + q_] += (int)(100 * (1 - sqrt((x-X)*(x-X) + (y-Y)*(y-Y))/R_d));
```

And to finalize the `map.data[]` I defined a global variable `_LETHAL 100` and inserted it like below

```
if(map.data[i]>_LETHAL) map.data[i] = _LETHAL;
```

I apologize for making this confusing, it seems that I'm not able to upload my program or any image because I just registered today...

But will very appreciate for any help...! Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275833/hi,-i-am-trying-to-write-a-code,-which-uses-nav_msgs%27s-occupancygrid/) by [Shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32616/shu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-14**:
Welcome! Code you please copy and paste your code here? It's actually better to do that vs. attaching it as a file.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-14**:
Also, no need to use `<br>` tags, you can just hit `Enter` to move to a new line. To enable syntax highlighting just copy & paste the code, highlight it, then click the `101010` (Preformatted Text) button.

**Comment by [Shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32616/shu/) on 2017-11-14**:
Hi jayess.
Thank you so much for the advice! I'll keep them in mind when I ask another question here.
I apparently figured it out! It seems that nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid's data value only receives up to 100. If it goes over that amount, it pushes out an error and I get weird visualized points.

**Comment by [Shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32616/shu/) on 2017-11-14**:
Thanks again for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I apparently figured it out! It seems that nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid's data value only receives up to 100. If it goes over that amount, it pushes out an error and I get weird visualized points.

---

Originally posted by [Shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32616/shu/) with karma: 36 on 2017-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0